# Croutons Bracha

Tags: blessing, food

What Bracha are the Croutons that are really just dried pieces of bread separately and when there in my instant soup and is there a difference?

Comment: Great question! This comes up for us so many times at a kiddush that often has croutons in the salad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way it works:

Bread that is cut into pieces retains its status of bread (i.e. Hamotzi) no matter how small the pieces get. So if you or anyone would cut the bread and then bake it again, it wouldn't matter and it would still be Hamotzi [unless you cut it less than a K'zayis an cook it in water-or fried in oil- to a certain degree... but not so practical]

However, there's a famous shitah (R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach) that holds that if companies make croutons - even though it's bread at an intermediate stage - since the end product will be croutons (which should be Mezonos for its own reasons) the entire product is Mezonos. In other words, it doesn't get a status of bread if the end-game is to make it into something else.

So in short:

- If it's homemade from bread it's Hamotzi (even in Salad - because it cannot become a Taful)
- If it's manufactured (like the way you say - i.e. made from bread) we have the above Machlokes
- If it's deep fried then it would appear everyone agrees it's mezonos.
- If it's a "yellow-type" crouton (i.e. deep fried and no where near bread) it's a clearcut Mezonos.

I'm not sure about the one's in instant soup (I've never personally come across them), but is seems they're like the second type mentioned above.

Enjoy!

Comment: yydl- why is the 2nd type a machlokes (other than the usual pas habaa b/kisnin issue)?

Comment: @YDK because if the manufacturer makes it into bread at one point - the it becomes Hamotzi, and cannot go back. Just about every manufacturer will make it that way...

Comment: Can you find the FAMOUS shitah you cant remeber and post it here thanks

Comment: I wrote I think R' Auerbach. Don't have it on hand though. Maybe tomorrow will show you...

Comment: @yydl- what's the machlokes?  It seems like a clear Mezonos!

Comment: Although I forgot about yellow soup nuts (duh, ST's talking about soup!).  That is actually a machlokes- whether deep-frying has the same status as boiling, though the minhag is to consider it equivelent.

Comment: Also, which manufacturers make it as bread? The kosher manufactured croutons I have seen are the Osem that fit into category 3 of pas habaa b'kisnin- meaning they are crunchy and are not made to eat as a food, but just a few at a time (S.A. O.C. 165:7, 3rd Yesh mefarshim + M.B 35).

Comment: Deep Frying there's no question: it was never made into soup. The only thing deep frying might do is for Kevias Seudah! And they don't make it as bread, but fact is that at one point it is bread. Or to put it another way: they make bread which is specifically for the production of croutons, and then make that bread into croutons. So that's where the machlokes comes in.

Comment: *Correction: it was never made into bread! not soup

Comment: Okay I also corrected the answer slightly. Plus I am now sure it was R' Auerbach

Comment: yydl- What about a caterer that makes croutons?  I am assuming they are specifically making it for croutons, not taking day old bread toasting it and making croutons.

Comment: It depends on what the bread was baked for. I'm not sure there are any caterers that bake bread specifically for croutons! (baking bread for "whatever" doesn't count). So if the caterer uses bread from a bakery, or bread they bake not specifically for bread, would appear to be Hamotzi according to all...

Comment: "since the end product will be croutons (which should be Mezonos for its own reasons)". why would it be mezonos if it comes from bread (which always retains its status)? I don't quite get the vort! Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Real croutons such that you would make yourself or have in a restaurant would be hamotzi.  It's just regular bread that was cut into pieces (Shulchan Aruch O.C 165:10.

Osem makes a number of crouton varieties.  These would be mezonos (S.A. O.C. 165:7, 3rd Yesh mefarshim + M.B 35)

Answer (score 2):

I heard in the name of the Rav Ovadia Yosef that it is Mezonot, if each piece is at least Kazayit you say Hamotzi.

Look at Hazon Ovadia page סה and סו, I think it would apply to our case, maybe I'm wrong, someone please correct me.

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable if you could add a source.

Answer (score 1):

The Yalkut Yosef in Siman 168 in the Berakhot English Edition Halacha 43 states

> If the Bread is not boiled, but someone placed small pieces in a bowl
> and they became fused together with honey or hot broth, the Halacha
> depends on the size of the original pieces. If they are as large as
> Kazayit, the blessing remains Hamotzi. If they are smaller than
> Kazayit, it then depends on their appearance.

As such, it seems that the size only matters when it becomes fused together with honey or hot broth, not when they are separate pieces.